# ASP.NET: Fill combo boxes from database without reloading page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm pretty new to web programming and ASP.NET though I have done a lot of programming on Windows forms in C#. I need to provide a set of comboboxes on my website so that it gets filled based on what the user selects in the previous combobox. Is AJAX/jQuery needed for this. What is the best way to do this and where can I find more resources to understand the basics. I am not using MVC.

Comment: I would think AJAX is the solution to this problem :S

Comment: To do this quickly, take a look at the AjaxToolkit. It's got a Cascading Combobox control that has most of the heavy lifting done for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the AjaxToolkit and built it yourself using jquery/AJAX or you can get a custom control that does it for you.

Here is an example showing you how to do it:
http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

This example uses PHP for the back end but you could just as easily add a WCF service that returns JSON. Here is a tutorial:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2008/08/23/returning-json-from-restful-interface-with-wcf.aspx

If you didn't feel comfortable building this yourself look at something like the Telrik RadCombo control.